# Refactor partial function with lambda

Tags: python

In the official docs [10.2. functools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html)
about partial

Roughly equivalent to:

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

I try to understand the universal structure with synonymous function.

```
partial = lambda func, *args, **kwargs: func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Does my understanding make sense?

Comment: BTW, `lambda` is intended as way to create anonymous functions, so it's generally considered bad style to assign a lambda to a name. See [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing two major things.

---

First, your version doesn't pass along the keyword arguments. To do that, you need to splat them as well:

```
lambda *args, **kwargs: func(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

But let's ignore that for the moment. The bigger problem is that you're missing the partial arguments, which is the entire point of `partial`. For example:

```
>>> def f(a, b):
...     return a + b
>>> add2 = partial(f, 2)
>>> add2(3)
5
>>> add2 = lambda *args: f(*args)
>>> add2(3)
f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

To do the same thing, you'd need to do this:

```
>>> add2 = lambda *args: f(2, *args)
>>> add2(3)
5
```

… or, equivalently:

```
>>> add2 = lambda *args: f(*((2,) + args))
>>> add2(3)
5
```

---

Also, there's no good reason to use `lambda` here. The point of `lambda` is that (a) you don't have to come up with a name, and (b) you can use it in an expression. If you're just going to use it in an assignment statement to give it a name, better to use `def`:

```
def add2(*args): return f(*((2,) + args))
```